# Proving Transformation defined as a matrix is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

I came across a problem thatwhile doing some review that states:
Consider the transformation $\textit{T}$:$\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$  defined by the matrix
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0  \\
        1 & 3  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Prove that the transformation is linear, state the kernel of T and find the image of the vector (1, 2) under this transformation.
For showing the linear transformation, I wrote in a more familiar fashion: *T($x_1$, $x_2$*) = (2$x_1$, $x_1$+$3x_2$). However, I am not stuck as to how to define the vectors/matrices for showing closure under addition and scalar multiplication. Any advice/solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u,v \in \mathbb R^2$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. If we prove that $T(\alpha u + v) = \alpha T(u)+T(v)$ then $T$ its a linear transformation.

Let $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $v = (v_1,v_2)$ for any $u_1,u_2,v_1, v_2, \alpha \in \mathbb R$ then:
$$\alpha u + v = \alpha(u_1,u_2)+(v_1,v_2)=(\alpha u_1+v_1,\alpha u_2 + v_2)$$

We calculate $T(\alpha u + v)$:
$$T(\alpha u + v)=T(\alpha u_1+v_1,\alpha u_2 + v_2)$$

$$=(2(\alpha u_1+v_1),(\alpha u_1+v_1)+3(\alpha u_2 + v_2))$$

$$=(2 \alpha u_1 + 2v_1,(\alpha u_1+3 \alpha u_2)+(v_1+3v_2))$$

$$=(2\alpha u_1,\alpha u_1+3 \alpha u_2)+(2v_1,v_1+3v_2)$$

$$=\alpha (2u_1, u_1+3u_2)+(2v_1,v_1+3v_2)=\alpha T(u)+T(v)$$

So $T$ is a linear transformation.

Forthe kernel of $T$, you only need to do Gauss elimination on the matrix and then find the free variables. In this case after doing Gauss elimination we find that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 3 \\
0 & -6 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This means that $ker(T) = \{0 \}$

You can calculate the image of $(1,2)$ directly simply put $T(1,2)$ or make the matrix multiplication:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 3 \\
0 & -6 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}$$

I hope it helps.